# Android TextView logcat warning: calling assumeLayout()

Tags: android, textview

I am repeatedly seeing the following warning message in my Android app's logcat output on a Google Pixel 6 running Android 12 (API 32):

`W/TextView: onProvideContentCaptureStructure(): calling assumeLayout()`

There is no further information logged. It appears numerous times whenever my app's activity is opened or refreshes. The activity contains several `TextView` elements in a `RelativeLayout` nested within a `ScrollView`.

I have been unable to find any guidance regarding this warning message. What is the issue, and/or how can I resolve it?